# show message when record doesnt exist

Tags: php, sql, pdo, crud

I have a database and a website with a textbox. the user can type in the name of a record in the database and then it will be deleted. What I want to add, but can't figure out how, is a way for the query to check if the name exists in the database and then delete it, if it doesn't exist it should display an error message. The error message is always visible for me with the code I have now.

```
<div class="main_content">
        <div class="header">Bestanden Verwijderen</div>
        <div class="info">
            <div>
            <form action="delete.php" method="post">
                <label for="id">Bestand Naam</label>                    
                <input type="text" name="name"  id="name">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>


            <?php

                $msg = '';
                // Check if POST data is not empty
                if (!empty($_POST)) {
                    // Post data not empty insert a new record
                    // Set-up the variables that are going to be inserted, we must check if the POST variables exist if not we can default them to blank
                    $name = isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != 'auto' ? $_POST['name'] : NULL;
                    // Check if POST variable "name" exists, if not default the value to blank, basically the same for all variables
                    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';                        
                }

                $sql = "DELETE FROM projects WHERE name = :name";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
                $count = $stmt->rowCount();// check affected rows using rowCount
                if ($count > 0) {
                    echo 'Bestand met de naam ' . $name . 'is verwijderd.';
                } elseif ($count == 0) {
                    echo "Bestand met die naam bestaat niet";
                }


            ?>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"The error message is always visible for me with the code I have now."_ - that's probably because you neglected to wrap that part into the `if` that checks whether this was a POST request ...? Not even the DELETE statement itself is wrapped into there - what sense would executing that statement make, if you did not even get any POST parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only populating `$name` if a POST request is sent, but the SQL query is always sent.

When the query is sent though, `$name` is not defined, so either `name` is checked against `null` or it fails entirely. Therefore the affected row count is always 0.

So what you need to do is extend your `if (!empty($_POST)) {` all the way to the end:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Post data not empty insert a new record
    // Set-up the variables that are going to be inserted, we must check if the POST variables exist if not we can default them to blank
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != 'auto' ? $_POST['name'] : NULL;
    // Check if POST variable "name" exists, if not default the value to blank, basically the same for all variables
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
    $sql = "DELETE FROM projects WHERE name = :name";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();// check affected rows using rowCount
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo 'Bestand met de naam ' . $name . 'is verwijderd.';
    } elseif ($count == 0) {
        echo "Bestand met die naam bestaat niet";
    }                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the if `if (!empty($_POST)) {` bellow the close of `if ($count > 0) {`

```
$msg = '';
// Check if POST data is not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Post data not empty insert a new record
    // Set-up the variables that are going to be inserted, we must check if the POST variables exist if not we can default them to blank
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != 'auto' ? $_POST['name'] : NULL;
    // Check if POST variable "name" exists, if not default the value to blank, basically the same for all variables
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';                        

    $sql = "DELETE FROM projects WHERE name = :name";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();// check affected rows using rowCount
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo 'Bestand met de naam ' . $name . 'is verwijderd.';
    } elseif ($count == 0) {
        echo "Bestand met die naam bestaat niet";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly,

- check if the name exist in the database. if it does, then
- delete it.

  `if ( !empty ( $_POST ) ) {`

  ```
    $name = (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != 'auto') ? $_POST['name'] : NULL;

    //Check if it exist in the database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE name = :name";
    $stmnt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmnt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmnt->execute();
    $rowCount = $stmnt->rowCount();
    if ($rowCount > 0){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM projects WHERE name = :name";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount()
        if ($count > 0) {
            echo 'The name ' . $name . ' has been deleted.';
        } 
    } else {
        echo 'The name ' . $name . ' was not found!';
        exit;
    }
  ```

  `}`

Thank you.